# How to check if a sequence matches another sequence

Tags: javascript

I am creating a little test game/ puzzle thing with JavaScript, CSS, php and HTML.

For part of it, in short, a set of buttons will appear with numbers 1-12 on them, and then people have to click them, in order, to complete it.

I think what I need to do, to stop people just straight away clicking '12' is set a piece of code somewhere as the 'role model code' and have the numbers 1-12 in them, then whatever set of numbers the player clicks it only proceeds if it matches the role model code.

Does anyone know how I would do this? If you don't get a particular part of my explanation please comment which part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sequentially enabling the buttons? eg the user can't click (2) if (1) hasn't been clicked yet?

Comment: Please post your code or at least an example so we can understand more about what data you're creating with the clicks that you want to compare to.  Is it just an array of clicked numbers in the order clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its mostly pseudo-code, but you should get the idea:

```
var mySequence=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var current=0;
...
your_click_handler_goes_here {
    var clicked =// the number of the button
    if(clicked==mySequence[current]){
        current+=1;
        proceed();
    }else{//user cant click this button yet
        return false;
    }
}
```